# npm, npx, and yarn. Which one is better?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, npx

I can see `create-react-app` has added installation with `npx`. So it made me curious to check which one is better `npm`, `npx` or `yarn`. Which one is better and which is better to use and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

npm: installation of packages (libraries), i.e. pieces of functionality to help you build your own applications.

npx: npx is a tool to execute packages without installing the packages.

yarn: also installation of packages. yarn is a replacement for npm that sits on top of the same packages repository.

Answer (score 2):

`npx` isn't the same as the other two, it is a feature of `npm` to run packages without installing. As for which one is better between `npm` and `yarn`, there isn't a clear "winner" (general rule to apply in life too). I personally prefer `yarn` since in my experience it was faster and less verbose, another positive was it had a lockfile but now `npm` has one too (and I hear new versions are faster as well).

tl;dr: Either is fine really.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the feature of npm and yarn. yarn is faster than npm because it is doing parallel installation and npm is doing serial installation of modules. Previous version of npm does not have lockfile now both npm and yarn have lock file. Both are build on the top of same repository.

npx is totally different from npm and yarn. It is a tool to execute packages without installing it.

So I will suggest yarn if you want to decrease the build time of the application.